# Custom Duration in SVDProgressHUD

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added `SVProgressHUD` via pods and added the following code. Everything works properly, but `alertview` stay longer (estimate around 4-5 seconds) than I want (1 second). I wonder is there a way to customize this duration.

```
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeNone];

[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Added to your cart."];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per documentation at https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

```
+ (void)setMinimumDismissTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval;
```

The display time depends on **minimumDismissTimeInterval** and **the length of the given string**.

so what you need to either configure it to **not dismiss w.r.t length of given string** or you can **dismiss it manually with delay** by calling method:

```
+ (void)dismissWithDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

or another work around is you can **set maximum dismiss time** to the time you want it to be dismissed .what it will do is dismiss SVProgressHUD irrespective of length of string.

```
+ (void)setMaximumDismissTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval;
```

but delay approach is best according to me.

Comment: `dismissWithDelay` is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Go to suvprogress.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame //search this method
 {
//...
   _minimumDismissTimeInterval = 2.0; //change the Time interval.

return self;
}
```

**Enjoy**

Comment: it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Search (_minimumDismissTimeInterval) in svprogress.m file  .It is 5.0 seconds by default just change it to 1.0 . It will works perfectly.

Comment: that is what I did, I put 1 seconds and even 0.5 sec. still longer.. I even just tested with 0.05 but I gurantee you that it stays at least 3 seconds.

Comment: this is the only way to change the alert time interval.

Comment: This breaks if you are using cocopods. They get changed everytime you update pods.